# Using twitter area search on a website with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I am struggling to find adequate documentation on using the twitter API to create a twitter side-bar on a website. I want the user to enter their suburb and the twitter feed should show tweets about the area.

Im not sure whether the embedded twitter widget can be used dynamically or whether the API is the correct way to address this

Any help or advice in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The embedded twitter widget can not be modified as far as I could tell, so the API is the way to go. [This](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) would be a good page to visit as it gives you an overview of how to search and gives examples of searching based on location. You also need to find a way to authenticate but that is fairly straight forward (look [here](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth)).

Comment: Thank you @EMH333, looking into it now.